# Why is pip install "installing collected packages" every time it runs?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I have a requirements file where I'm installing several packages. When I run `pip install` the first time in a new environment, they install as they should. Thereafter, most of my packages are correctly reporting "Requirement already satisfied" and not installing again.

However, one of my packages, for some reason, is "Installing collected packages" every time, executing setup.py, etc. This is actually my own internal library that's hosted on my own server and being installed via git+ssh.

Here's a look at what's happening. (The library is called django-supplement.)

```
$ pip install -r requirements/production.txt 
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django from git+https://github.com/django/django.git@1.6b2#egg=django in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements/production.txt (line 3))
Downloading/unpacking django- from git+ssh://XXXXXXXX/gits/django_supplement@1.6#egg=django_supplement (from -r requirements/production.txt (line 4))
  Cloning ssh://XXXXXXXX/gits/django_supplement (to 1.6) to ./build/django-supplement
  Running setup.py egg_info for package django-supplement

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): mailsnake from git+https://github.com/Leftium/mailsnake.git#egg=mailsnake in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements/production.txt (line 5))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): MySQL-python==1.2.4 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements/common.txt (line 1))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): South==0.7.3 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements/common.txt (line 2))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-memcached==1.47 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements/common.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django-model-utils==1.0.0 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements/common.txt (line 5))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django-localflavor==1.0 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements/common.txt (line 6))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django-countries==1.0.5 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements/common.txt (line 7))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): gunicorn==18.0 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements/common.txt (line 9))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): wsgiref==0.1.2 in /usr/lib/python2.7 (from -r requirements/common.txt (line 10))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): markdown2>=1.0.1.19 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from django-supplement->-r requirements/production.txt (line 4))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): distribute in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from mailsnake->-r requirements/production.txt (line 5))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools>=0.7 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from distribute->mailsnake->-r requirements/production.txt (line 5))
Installing collected packages: django-supplement
  Running setup.py install for django-supplement

Successfully installed django-supplement
Cleaning up...
```

And here's what setup.py looks like in django-supplement:

```py
import os
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

# Utility function to read the README file.
# Used for the long_description.  It's nice, because now 1) we have a top level
# README file and 2) it's easier to type in the README file than to put a raw
# string in below ...
def read(fname):
    return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)).read()

setup(
    name = "django_supplement",
    version = "1.6.1",
    author = "Jim Dalton",
    author_email = "XXXXXXXX",
    description = "Common helpers for django",
    license = "BSD",
    packages=find_packages(),
    long_description=read('README'),
    install_requires=["markdown2 >= 1.0.1.19"],
)
```

So what I'd like to do is find a way to make my library behave like normal libraries, and install once for a given version and otherwise report "Requirement already satisified" unless i use the --upgrade flag or whatever.

FYI the reason I care is that I'm configuring a project in Ansible right now, and the fact that it's reporting "Successfully installed..." is causing Ansible to think there's been a change, which triggers other actions I'd prefer to avoid during configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I fixed this but I'm not sure why. The name kwarg I was passing to setup I guess was not aligning with something. Renaming to django-supplement solved the problem.